# Socrata, SODA, REST, JS: How to query number of rows?

Tags: javascript, rest, socrata, soda

I'm trying to figure out how to query a resource to see how many rows it has before I request the entire resource at once, or whether I use paging to bring back rows in batches.

For example, this resource here:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/Bicycle-Routes/7vsa-caz7

1) In cases where I know the number of rows, I can use the [$limit parameter](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html) to ensure I get back everything. For example, this dataset has about 17,000 rows, so giving it a $limit of 20000 gets all of them.

For example:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/cc5c-sm6z.geojson?$limit=20000

also...

2) I thought maybe to make a [metadata call](https://socratametadataapi.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/endpoints), but while this request here returns metadata, number of rows is not part of it:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/metadata/v1/cc5c-sm6z

However, I would like to know how many rows are in the dataset before I decide how to request them: all at once with the $limit parameter, or paging with the $limit and $offset parameters.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method could be to count the rows using the [COUNT](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/count.html) function in the API call.

Should note that YMMV on this approach. Generally, the maximum is around [50,000 rows](https://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html) before you need to switch to paging. Generally, I'll always throw a 50k limit and have paging ready if it's larger.